# Forcing gcc to only look in one directory for library files

Tags: c, gcc

So I am making a C application and I have all the library files `.so` , `.a` etc in a `./lib` directory in the same directory as my C application.

I am compiling my C application with the `-L./lib` flag.
But it seems to me that gcc still looks for libraries within `/usr/lib` `/usr/local/lib` etc .

Is there a way to force gcc to only look for library files in my `./lib` directory?
So if I remove the `./lib` folder the application won't compile because it can't find the libraries.

Comment: You can use -nodefaultlibs. Note that this will prevent you to link against the libc, so you will have to provide its path.

Comment: Correction: -nodefaultlibs will prevent gcc from linking with needed lib. You may prefer `-Wl,-z,nodefaultlib`, which tells the linker to not search in the default lib paths.